Is there a way to subscribe event bridge event bus to SNS topics?
I have multiple external publishers publishing on SNS topics that my service listens to. I need to route these message to some sort of priority queue (SQS).
Is there a way to have this pattern natively? If yes how?
SNS -> Event Bridge Rules -> SQS (P0 - PN)

OR do I need to consume the SNS messages in a SQS first?
SNS -> SQS -> Event Bridge Rules -> SQS (P0 - PN)

I am trying to avoid creating the initial SQS as it seems a waste of resources and increased management.

What do you mean by "priority queue" ? Priority relative to what?

Why note fanout directly from the SNS to the SQS queues?
Like: SNS -> SQS (P0 - PN)
I think that's the standard in this case.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-sqs-as-subscriber.html



I have rules that may become complicated overtime. I prefer managing all the rules at a single place than individual filter policies


I want to leverage Event Bridge pipes to enrich the events in the near future



I don't know the specific requirements of your pipeline, but it seems that eventbridge rules is not the place for this.
Eventbridge is made to work on AWS events. The content of an SNS message is not an AWS event. Maybe what you want is a Lambda function to process the events.
Like SNS -> SQS -> Lambda -> SQS (P0 - PN) or something like Kinesis Streams or Firehose https://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/introduction.html
